# web GRPC and Iroha (JS implementation for iroha)

Tags: grpc, hyperledger-iroha

I am trying to run this docker file https://gitlab.com/snippets/1713665

[consoles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gn1C.png)

I have running iroha container as you can see in right console on 50051 port, but on running the above docker file for web GRPC then you can see in left console it is unable to make connection. as i have also tried with enabling and disabling the firewalls  and also with opening the 50051 withudo ufw allow 50051 sudo ufw allow 50051 ...But in the end i have the same results
"Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:50051: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...  system=system"

I have also posted this issue month ago but no once gave me any response, Thats why i am reposting with further elaboration

Comment: @DazWilkin could you please help

Answer (score 0):

Try running the grpc web proxy, with the backend address as localhost, instead of whatever is default in the gitlab post.

ex. ./grpcwebproxy-v0.13.0-osx-x86_64 --backend_addr=localhost:50051     --run_tls_server=false

From the console logs, it looks like it is trying to connect to dev.localdomain:50051